# Text overlapping with too much text on hover

Tags: html, css

I have tried a few things but seem to be getting nowhere, I can move the text by changing the 'position' tag, but this seems to result in the text kinda vanishing into the boxes edge and being oddly spaced..  I am guessing I have coded this up that its fine on less text, but when adding too much, I get a overlap.. anyway I can shift things about a tad so they look nicely laid out?

Website; http://outside.hobhob.uk
Referring to the text which appears when you hover over the portfolio items in the grid.  I need the title to stay at the top, but avoid the description underneath overlapping with the header.

Code snippet of the grid section;

```
            <div class="portfolio-item item tile entry">
                <a href="single.html">
                    <img src="content/portfolio_07.png" alt="">
                   <div class="magnifier">
                        <div class="buttons">
                         <h4>Melbourne Design Guide</h4>
                         <p>Creative mapping and Illustration for the cities annual design guide</p>
                        </div><!-- end buttons -->
                    </div><!-- end magnifier --> 
                </a>
            </div><!-- end item -->
```

CSS I am looking at.. maybe this is where I am going wrong?

```
.buttons.blog-style p,
.magnifier p,
#gallery .caption p {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    bottom: 20px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: "Raleway";
    font-size: 16px !important;
    left: 30px;
    line-height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none !important;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.buttons.blog-style h4,
.magnifier h4,
#gallery .caption h3 {
font-size:28px !important;
line-height:28px;
font-family:"HighVoltage" !important;
display: inline-block;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
position:absolute;
left:30px;
bottom:60px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform: none !important;
background-color:transparent;
text-shadow:none;
border-width:0px;
border-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-style:none;

}
```

Comment: Not reproducible, or am I [seeing](http://imgur.com/2gppZKL) something else?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What text are you referring to?? This is really vague for me. Can you make a codepen that reproduces the issue and points it out in specific?

Comment: Sorry guys!  I mean the text when you hover over the image/placeholder which appears.  if you hover over a few, you will see what I mean.

Apologies for not being clear on that!

Comment: did you check my answer ? if yes....comment if it's ok or what do you exactly want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you want the h4 to always be on the bottom of the `.button` and if i understood right you want something like this :

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/c65w034p/)**

if an item has absolute position and you don't want it to overlap other items , you need to create a space for that item.

you need to add this css in order to work

```
.buttons { 
  position:relative
}
.buttons.blog-style p,
.magnifier p,
#gallery .caption p {
  padding-bottom:88px;
}
.buttons.blog-style h4,
.magnifier h4,
#gallery .caption h3 {
  margin:0;
}
```

where `88px` is a sum between `bottom:60px` you have on the description and the height of the description `line-height:28px;`

i added `margin:0` on the description because it just isn't necessary anymore. but if you want to keep that margin...add it to the `padding-bottom:88px`

Comment: Hey,

This helps stop the text overlapping, but results in the the title being above the description.  I also still have the issue of the text vanishing off the box edge on some of the boxes with longer sentences.. This is a huge help though in getting me where I need to be :) 

Thanks

Comment: Ah! Figured it out, I added what you mentioned, but removed the section for buttons to be relative, as I have that code already within the other sections.  But removing the left borders all together got the text to stop vanishing.  :) Thanks loads, your edits helped me figure this out!